# Datadog checks not appearing in Datadog console

Tags: datadog

This is the installation path of datadog `/etc/datadog-agent`
Under this we have checks under folder `/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d`

Under this we have defined a service to report disk space alert under disk.d
`/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/disk.d`

```
disk.d]# ls *.yaml
disk.yaml
```

We have the file ready in the configuration. We did tried to reload the datadog agent to reflect the changes.

The expected scenario is it should reflect in datadog console under the service defined 
The query we are using is

```
avg(last_5m):max:system.disk.in_use{esb,nonproduction} by {host,device} > 0.9
```

But we are unable to establish anything.

Nutshell none of the alerts configured for this host are not reflecting in datadog console.

Comment: paste the content of disk.yaml and the `datadog-agent status` output please

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove the scope first and test again the data-points, if none, proceed and editing the 'average by' host to host.name